# How to automatically delete files created with File::Temp when program stops unexpectedly?

Tags: perl

I am creating temp files with File::Temp. My temp files are deleted automatically when the program exits normally. I expected the same to happen when my program is stopped with ctrl+c. It is not.

Here's a simple program demonstrating my problem.

The desired behavior is this. How can I achieve it? I am on Linux.

- temp file is not deleted when closing the file handle (ok)
- temp file gets deleted when program exits normally (ok)
- temp file gets deleted when program exits with ctrl+c (not working)

.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use warnings; use strict;
use File::Temp qw(tempfile tmpfile);

my $fh = File::Temp->new;
close $fh;

-f "$fh" || die "$fh does not exist"; 
print "hit enter and the file will be deleted";
print "hit ctrl+c and it won't";
print "verify with ls $fh after program exits";
readline STDIN;
```

EDIT 1

I tested the behavior of tempfile. It seems to confirm that Linux supports what I am looking for (marking files as temp / unlinking open file). I seem to have idealized File::Temp somehow.

```
# program will die because os deletes tmpfile after close
my $fh = tempfile;
close $fh;
stat $fh || die;
readline STDIN;
```

Comment: @ikegami : He's on Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cause a Control_C keyboard interrupt to run your `END` block you will need to add a signal handler. Compare the behavior of:

```
perl -E 'END{say "END"};<STDIN>'
```

with:

```
perl -E '$SIG{INT}=sub{die};END{say "END"};<STDIN>'
```

From the [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html)

```
An END code block is executed as late as possible, that is, after perl has
finished running the program and just before the interpreter is being exited,
even if it is exiting as a result of a die() function. (But not if it's
morphing into another program via exec, or being blown out of the water by a
signal--you have to trap that yourself (if you can).)
```

Comment: I am interested with a solution that's as transparent as possible, especially that my OS supports cleaning up temp files automatically.

Comment: The signal handler is the most portable solution, and it allows me not to change my program.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting your cleanup code in and END block?

Comment: Are you sure the END block is called when a script is aborted with ctrl+c? I did a quick test and found it is not: perl -e 'END{print "END\n"} readline STDIN'

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source code. I even checked the latest version (0.22 as of writing). What I want to do with File::Temp is not allowed by design.

When an object is created, the temp file is created using an array context as:

```
sub new {
  ...
  # Open the file and retain file handle and file name
  my ($fh, $path) = tempfile( @template, %args );
```

Creating a tempfile in a array context implies the file will never be unlinked automatically (even on platform supporting it). The file is marked for deferred unlink, which mean it will be deleted when the program exits normally.

```
sub tempfile { 
  ...
  _deferred_unlink($fh, $path, 0) if $options{"UNLINK"};

  # Return
  if (wantarray()) {

    if ($options{'OPEN'}) {
      return ($fh, $path);
    } else {
      return (undef, $path);
    }

  } else {

    # Unlink the file. It is up to unlink0 to decide what to do with
    # this (whether to unlink now or to defer until later)
    unlink0($fh, $path) or croak "Error unlinking file $path using unlink0";

    # Return just the filehandle.
    return $fh;
  }
```

If I want to keep using File::Temp, I need to setup a signal handler to force clean up when my program aborts. I should also setup a sig handler if portability is of any concern, because deferred unlink is all that's offered on some platforms. The nice thing is, File::Temp creates a END block so there isn't much at all to do:

```
use sigtrap qw(die normal-signals error-signals);
```

If portability is not a concern and the platform supports automatic file cleanup, then using tempfile is ok (in scalar context).

The rationale behind this design is well explained by the following comment:

> we have to indicate temporary-ness when we open the file. **In general
>   we only want a true temporary file if we are returning just the
>   filehandle - if the user wants the filename they probably do not want
>   the file to disappear as soon as they close it (which may be important
>   if they want a child process to use the file)**

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the file name? If not, use

```
my $fh = tempfile();
```

Comment: I don't absolutely need it but it fits my current implementation well. I redirect many system commands in temp files later on. Seems easier done through a filename than a handle.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, and I think I found a reasonably good, small solution.

It's nothing fundamentally new, but perhaps simpler than installing your own `END` blocks, etc:

```
use sigtrap qw(die INT); # ensures DESTROY methods are run on Ctrl-C

my $temp = File::Temp->new(UNLINK => 1);
my $filename = $temp->filename;
# When $temp goes out of scope, the file will be
# deleted, and $filename will be invalid.
# Further, a Ctrl-C will cause $temp->DESTROY to be invoked,
# which will also delete the temp file.
```